# Enlarge android app launch icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I used the launcher icon generator link below to create my own launcher icon:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Then I  download the zip package. Unzip it into the right directory and  overwrite all the drawable-*/ic_launcher.png correctly with my launcher images.

The problem is that the launcher icon is small compared to other icons on my phone. Look at the image on the far right below:

[image]

How do I enlarge it's dimensions in android studio ?

Comment: I would appreciate if instead of down voting.. someone could tell me what's wrong with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit those Mipmaps and enlarge them a bit.
 Use [this](http://resizeimage.net/) website, upload any of your icon (for better results use the larger one), edit sizes of every icon like you could multiply every icon's width and height by 1.25 and put them. 
For Example - 

192x192 => 240x240 *[xxxhdpi]*

144x144 => 180x180 *[xxhdpi]*

96x96   => 120x120 *[xhdpi]*

72x72   => 90x90   *[hdpi]*

48x48   => 60x60 *[mdpi]*

- Also, Don't change any option on the website, just upload the file,

[image]

- Enter the dimensions

[image]

- Click on resize

[image]

- Then download them

[image]
.
 I used this way and it worked great.
 Also, you could use photoshop but by the time photoshop will open, your work will be done.
And Downvotes are because of something you could do by yourself or something you could find on google or something hard enough to answer. Don't panic, even I can't post questions because I've more downvotes than upvotes on my questions.
Also, don't forget to name all the files `ic_launcher.png` and store them in respective mipmap folder.